Unsafe floor in a house
Please consider the following hypothetical situation:
A person living alone in an old house has a floor that he believes to be safe. He is not  breaking the law. The police get a report that illegal activity is going on in his house. They get a search warrant and 10 officers to show up to search the house. Several of the officers are over 200 pounds in weight.
Unfortunately, the floor gives way and one officers is killed and several officers are badly hurt. They do not find any illegal activity in the home.
Is the owner of the  home civilly liable for death of an officer and for injuries to the other officers? Do the police have any civil liability here for damage to the home?

Presumably an important question would be whether the man was negligent in maintaining the floor, and whether his belief in its safety was reasonable. You haven't given any facts relevant to those questions.

"Several of the officers are over 200 pounds in weight." A 200 lb male is 58th percentile, i.e. 42 of 100 men are heavier than that, so it's a perfectly normal weight. What they design things like cars for is the 95th percentile male which is now around 284 lbs.

@user71659 It might be more like Bob doesn't go to the attic anymore because he knows or strongly suspects that the floor won't hold a grownups weight anymore. Or maybe, one person being very careful is fine but 3 people randomly walking around is not.

Did the house pass inspection when built? Were any modifications made without proper permitting and inspection?

@JonCuster The house passed inspection when it was built. All the modifications were made with the proper permitting. However, it has not been inspected by a professional in the last 5 years.

@NateEldredge  Assume the person has done a reasonable job maintaining the floor. However, some home owners, say 5%, would have done more.

@MichaelHall: Since what OP is describing should be within the design limits of a reasonable floor, I was assuming the floor had suffered some kind of damage or deterioration (e.g. rot, termites, earthquake, fire, ...) that the owner was not aware of.  So "maintenance" would consist of inspecting the floor and its support structures to detect the damage, and making appropriate repairs.  Given the above comments from OP, I take it that the damage was such that reasonable inspections would not have discovered it.

OP: was the cause of the collapse determined?  Design defect, shoddy construction, damage from termites or rot, deliberate sabotage, etc?  What steps would have been needed to detect and repair the issue?  Why did the owner not take them, and would a reasonable person have done the same?


Is the owner of the home civilly liable for death of an officer and
for injuries to the other officers?

State law varies considerably on the civil liability to the officers point.
The common law rule imposed different rules for trespassers, licensees, and invitees, with the duty towards trespassers limited to a bar on setting deadly traps, towards licensees basically ordinary negligence, and towards invitees, basically the highest standard of care. The officers are either trespassers or licensees for this purpose. And there is probably no duty to warn since the police presence was not reasonably foreseen.
Other states have adopted a general negligence rule.
Overall, it is unlikely that there would be liability but it isn't an open and shut case.

Do the police have any civil liability here for damage to the home?

No. There is a general police activity exception to takings clause liability under the 5th and 14th Amendments, and their actions were not unreasonable within the meaning of the 4th and 14th Amendments' prohibition on unreasonable searches and seizures.

canada
This would fall to be assessed under ordinary negligence principles or Occupier Liability Acts. Both generally place an obligation on the occupier of a premise to take all reasonable care in the circumstances to see that a person will be reasonably safe in using the premises.
The duty is established by being in a position to inspect, maintain, improve, warn, etc. with respect to the property.
The standard is that one do what is reasonable in the circumstances.
You have clarified in comments that we are to assume that the occupier has "done a reasonable job maintaining the floor."
Given that, there would be no liability in negligence or under Occupier Liability Acts.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
